# What does in $L^2$ sense mean?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

What does it mean when we have for example:

$$f=\sum\limits_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} \langle f,e_k\rangle e_k\quad \text{in }L^2(\mathbb{R}) \text{ sense}?$$
Does this equation hold for almost every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ or with respect to the convergence in the $L^2$-norm?

Comment: $f\in L²(ℝ)$ and $e_k$ is an orthonormalbasis of L²(ℝ),$ <.,.>$ denotes the scalar product.

Answer (score 1):

It means $\int |f-S_n|^{2} \to 0$ where $S_n$ is the $n-$th partial sum of the series.

Comment: Thank you, but does this equation hold also for almost every $x\in ℝ$?

Comment: No, it does not give almost everywhere convergence. @anjo1659

Comment: Thank you, but I often read $$f(x)=\sum<f,e_k>e_k(x)\quad \text{in }L²(ℝ).$$ Does this also mean the convergence with respect to the L²-norm?

Comment: @anjo1659 : Yes, convergence with respect to the $L^2$-norm is what would be meant.

Answer (score 1):

It means that 
$$||f - \sum\limits_{k= -n}^n \langle f,e_k\rangle e_k||_2  \to 0$$

as $n \to \infty.$